# Capitalize string between quotes with sed

Tags: unix, sed

Background: I am moving some sql statements from SQL server to Oracle. While Oracle is case sensitive in string comparison, SQL server is not, by default I think.
In my case all strings have to be in upper case.

in the original I might have something like

```
xyz like '%foo%' and ...
```

which I want to convert to

```
xyz like '%FOO%' and ...
```

i.e. anything between quotes following 'like ' has to be capitalised.

---

here is what I have tried and does not work:

```
echo "like 'aaa' aaa"|sed 's/like\( '.*'\)/like\U\1/g'
```

for some reason this gives me

```
like 'AAA' AAA
```

I don't understand why it matches the whole line, even after the second quote.

This does also not work:

```
echo "like 'aaa' aaa"|sed 's/like\( '[^']*\)/like\U\1/g'
```

why? I don't understand the error message `sed: -e expression #1, char 26: unterminated 's' command`

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the question here? You say you never used quotes before?

Comment: @hek2mgl ehm, no? Where did I say that? Did you read the question?

Comment: It's unclear to me how you could try to use quotes inside quotes then

Comment: I read it again (and again). So you basically asking why `echo "like 'aaa' aaa"|sed 's/like\( '.*'\)/like\U\1/g'` "worked" ?

Comment: In that case I recommend to `set -x` before running the `sed` command to see how the shell actually expands `.*`

Comment: Please see my comment on the accepted answer. I tried escaping the quotes with a backslash, which did not work in that case.

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks for the `set -x`, this shows what Sundeep explained in his edited answer and comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `'s/SEARCH/REPLACE/'` with outer single quotes, you cannot use single quotes inside it as well... but there is a workaround with using `\x27` instead

```
$ echo "like 'aaa' aaa"|sed 's/like\( \x27.*\x27\)/like\U\1/g'
like 'AAA' aaa
```

These two are equivalent, `'s/like\( '.*'\)/like\U\1/g'` is simply three strings concatenated `'s/like( '` and `.*` and `'\)/like\U\1/g'`

```
$ echo "like 'aaa' aaa" | sed 's/like\( '.*'\)/like\U\1/g'
like 'AAA' AAA
$ echo "like 'aaa' aaa" | sed 's/like\( .*\)/like\U\1/g'
like 'AAA' AAA

$ # a different example
$ echo "like 'aaa' aaa" | sed 's/like/'LIKE'/g'
LIKE 'aaa' aaa
```

Also, `.*` will try to match as much as possible, so use this instead:

```
$ echo "xyz like '%foo%' and 'bar' ..." | sed 's/\(like[^\x27]*\x27\)\([^\x27]*\)/\1\U\2/g'
xyz like '%FOO%' and 'bar' ...
```

vs

```
$ echo "xyz like '%foo%' and 'bar' ..." | sed 's/like\( \x27.*\x27\)/like\U\1/g'
xyz like '%FOO%' AND 'BAR' ...
```

- `like[^\x27]*\x27` matches `like` followed by non-single quote character and a single quote character
- `[^\x27]*` then we match as many non-single quote characters as possible which will then be subjected to `\U` in replacement section

Comment: Thanks! I suspected sth like that. I tried escaping the quote with a backslash, but that didn't work. So I assumes sed would determine the end of the command after the third slash. One question though: You know why my first example even worked then?

Comment: 'worked' in a way of not crashing and producing part of the desired output?

Comment: that is because `'s/like\( '.*'\)/like\U\1/g'` is actually multiple strings concatenated... `s/like\( ` and `.*` and `\)/like\U\1/g`... the `.*` happily matched everything... it is equivalent to `s/like\( .*\)/like\U\1/g` ... also see `echo "like 'aaa' aaa" | sed 's/like/'LIKE'/g'` for example

Comment: Thanks. this helped my understanding. Your edited answer is then I think almost equivalent to my second try, when using \x27 instead of the single quote?

Comment: yup, you got it right `\x27` instead of `'` ... I actually didn't bother with it after seeing error, or I would have based my answer just on that...

Answer (score 1):

You can use double quotes to protect the single quotes, like so:

```
echo "like 'aaa' aaa" | sed "s/like\( '[^']*'\)/like\U\1/g"
```

Outputs:

```
like 'AAA' aaa
```

Comment: Thanks. Using double quotes in that case is a possibility I was unaware of

Comment: You may want to take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42082956/6862601